# Right join does not return null values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, right-join

My tables are:

```
allowed(resourceid, personid)
person(personid, email)
```

I want to print out whether a person has the right to access a resource, lets say with the resourceid = 2.
The result should be:

```
personright(personid, email, resourceid)
```

and resourceid should be null if the person is not allowed to access resource 2. If the person is allowed to access 2, resourceid should be 2.

So I expect that everytime my query is executed that the whole user list is printed out.

I had a working solution using a subquery, but I want to do this with a join.

```
select person.personid, person.email, allowed.resourceid
from person 
right join allowed on(person.personid = allowed.personid)
where (allowed.resourceid IS NULL OR allowed.resourceid = 2);
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your description of problem - it should be **left join** here, not right join.

```
select person.personid, person.email, allowed.resourceid
from person 
    left join allowed on person.personid = allowed.personid and allowed.resourceid = 2
```

Also note I've moved `allowed.resourceid = 2` condition from `where` clause to the join condition. Thus if there are no matching records in `allowed` table having `resourceid = 2` and `personid` equals to appropriate `personid` from `person` table - you will get null as `allowed.resourceid` exactly as it was required.

Comment: @Babs it is not a typo, it was intended. See updated answer.